# Node js require not working in directory out of src

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I have the problem, that `require` can not find modules installed via `npm`.

I have the following project structure (short):

- mod

  - sampleModule

    - main.js
- src

  - app.js
  - package.json
  - provider

    - modProvider.js

I load all **mod**s in the `modProvider.js` which is called in the `app.js`. But when i use `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` it could not find the module. In `app.js` and `modProvider.js` every works fine).

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Load module code:

```
var modMainJs = require('../../mod/' + config.serverModules[i].name + '/main.js');
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you installed mongoose module(should be in the node_module dir)?

Comment: Yes, in app.js it works